# Simulate website load on Node.JS

Tags: node.js, performance-testing

I am thinking of creating my own simple load test, where I can hit my website with multiple requests (like 100-1000 concurrent users) to see how it performs. I want to try Node.js out, but I don't know if it is the wrong technology for the job, since Node.js don't use threads?
Can I with the async model that Node.js uses, simulate the many user requests, or would that be more appropiate to do in another language like Ruby/.NET/Python?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use node, rather than the likes of [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) or [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html)?

Comment: I know there exists multiple frameworks for it, but I do it mainly for 2 reasons. To improve my programming skills (it is just a small hobby project), and to be able to test ajax calls (I don't think too many of the tools have that option, since they don't interpret the Javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js ought to be perfect for the task. I do this at work. The one crucial piece that you will have to change is the http socket pool. The following code snipped will disable pooling entirely, letting you starve your Node.js process if you want to.

```
var http = require('http');
var req = http.request(..., agent: false)
```

You can read about this more at the [http.Agent documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_agent).

Your concern about threads is astute, but even if you hit that limit (Node is very good at keeping your resources efficient) the solution is simple: start multiple instances (processes) of your load test. As it is, you may have to use multiple machines entirely to correctly simulate load.

In any case, you will not win automatically by using Ruby or Python for this. Asynchronous programming is *ideal* for I/O and network-bound tasks, and Node excels at this. Similarly, while Ruby and Python *have* third-party asynchronous frameworks, they're by definition more obscure than the *standard* asynchronous framework given in Node.

Comment: Thanks, also for the tip about disabling the pooling.

Answer (score 1):

Node can fire off pretty much as many requests as you want it to (though you may have to change the defaults for `http:Agent`). You're more likely to be limited by what your OS can do than by anything inherent in node (and of course such limitations will apply in any other language you use).

Answer (score 0):

It's simple to create load tests with [nodeload](https://github.com/benschmaus/nodeload).